# Strip html tags in Javascrip/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way how I can strip the html tags in an textarea body, when I insert the data in mysql I use PHP BBCODE for Youtube videos like [vide=link] and in the edit textarea I use Javascript and outputs html tags instead of PHP BBCODE like [video=link]

Javascript textarea:

```
var currentComment = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
var editText = '<div class="contact-form-area"><form id="post_form2"><div class="row"><div class="col-12"><textarea name="post_content2" id="post_content'+id+'" class="edit_comment">'+currentComment+'</textarea></div><div class="col-12"><input type="hidden" class="id_content" id="'+id+'" /><button type="button" class="cancel btn vizew-btn" style="float:left;" data-message="'+currentComment+'" id="'+id+'"> Cancel</button> <button type="button" class="save btn vizew-btn" id="'+id+'" style="float:right;"> Save</button></div></div></form></div>';
```

[Image of exposed html tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRDAq.png)

I tried usign this escape function but didn't worked out.

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe)
{
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

I want to know if is a way to print the PHP BBCODE in the textarea instead of the hmtl tags.

Comment: `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Don't use `.html()` to get the textarea input, use `.val()`. That will parse it to normal text.

Comment: I tried now using .val() instead but the textarea when I edit the content is blank, it doesn't display any text

Comment: @ScottPascal use `.text();` , the textarea will be retrieved as plain text, without any HTML tags, if you want a BBCODE to html, try look this as reference https://github.com/chriskonnertz/bbcode or https://github.com/dedalozzo/converter

Comment: Why are you populating your textarea with/from the rendered HTML code, and not with what you originally stored into the database? Just stripping out HTML tags now would not even make much sense, assuming that you _replaced_ the `[video=link]` with HTML code - because then you would _lose_ that video link at that point. That code itself is not contained in the _text_ any more, and if you strip away the HTML code you replaced it with - then what's _left_ ...?